# When are command options prefixed with two hyphens `--`?

Tags: command-line

What are the general rules for knowing when command options are prefixed by `--` as opposed to `-`?

Edit: An answer referencing a canonical source, such as steeldriver's is preferred. One suggested duplicate refers to Wikipedia which is okay but probably not as good as a GNU documentation link.

Second edit: I think the title is not my original so if it misleads, I'm sorry, it was not my edit. That probably explains why some comments direct me to the man page.

Comment: I don't understand the question, there's no rule, that's a developer's / developers' choice, it's totally up to the specific tool.

Comment: You may find this a useful staring point: [Program Argument Syntax Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

Comment: That looks like it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: There can be no canonical source for this, since there are many software developers and all of them do not agree to any common convention.

Comment: @muru couldn't be right more.

Comment: I find the GNU link more valuable than the stackoverflow links thus far and the dupe suggestion because the GNU link is brief, explains some of the history, and appears to be fairly canonical to me if you accept that canonical rules can be broken in some circumstances, which I do.

Comment: You should really rephrase the question, because as you can see every answer is addressing a different aspect of the topic. What do you want to know exactly? The literal answer to your question is "look at the `man` page", but you seem to be wanting to learn about the possible conventions and if there are differences in the usage. Can you clarify what you want to know exactly?

Comment: It don't think "general rules" needs to be rephrased. I don't think man pages are general. They're specific.

Comment: @H2ONaCl read your own comment. You just classified your own question as "opinion based". If more then one way exist, obviously there are no general rules, the choice is subjective.

Comment: It disagree that choice is subjective when there is a convention. I disagree that seeking knowledge of the convention implies that a convention must not be broken. I disagree that seeking "general rules" is seeking opinion.

Comment: jacob vlijm, there obviously are "general rules". steeldriver has linked to a GNU description of the convention.

Comment: I think we're in a loop here, and no offence, but why do you not understand that *if* there are more then one used practices, the choice for either one of them is subjective. In different area's of applications, different conventions are (often) used. Why would either one of them be incorrect? As @kos already mentioned, the `man` pages tell you what you need to know. You'll need to read them anyway to know the options to begin with.

Comment: I'm sorry but I agree with Jacob Vlijm. Each convention has its pros / cons, and when more than one avails the choice merely depends on a preference. The fact that they're called "conventions" itself implies that each it's just one way to do it. So this question is currently not answerable, as there's no rule, any of the mentioned convention avails if used correctly. Asking for a comparison of conventions instead would be a totally legit (and IMO also interesting) question.

Comment: jacob vlijm, the choice is not subjective, the GNU link says there is a convention and both belong in the convention and so supporting one, the other, or both, would be conventional. Supporting a third way would be an acceptable violation of the convention if there is a reason to violate.

Comment: kos, I disagree the question is not answerable. The question seeks a description of the convention when it asks "what are the general rules" and the GNU link from steeldriver describes what is generally done.

Comment: Then as I said 2 comments ago you should rephrase the question. "When is X used as opposed to Y?" 1) implies that either X or Y must be preferred: it's not like that, as it has been said already a zillion times, and adding to that many tools use both X and Y. 2) You edited saying that the title is not yours, which is true, but that title fits perfectly what you're effectively asking in the body. You edited the question specifying that the title is misleading, but instead of specifying that you should rather edit it along with the body, because both the title and the body imply 1).

Comment: @muru, why you think there cannot be a canonical source. Given the definition "conforming to orthodox or well-established rules or patterns" it appears that the GNU link is a match because it offers a description for what is "well-established".

Comment: @H2ONaCl I have said why in my comment. Canonical in terms of conventions would be a standard that defines such a convention, not just "conforming to orthodox or well-established" whatever. http://english.stackexchange.com/a/34926/93130

Comment: @muru, I think if an authority describes a convention and documents that there have been exceptions or violations, does not necessarily make the write-up not canonical. May be we are both splitting hairs but given the looseness around internet standards I have relaxed my expectations in general.

Comment: Then your question is answered by the linked post, or too broad.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the single dash `-` introduces single letter options, where the letter is a mnemonic for the name of the option.

The double dash `--` introduces long option names, where the name of the option is a whole word.

AFAIK this convention was introduced in the 1980's by the FSF GNU utilities. Note that the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) recommends single dash options, except for a double dash to indicate the end of the option list.

See also

- [When and how was the double-dash (--) introduced as an end of options delimiter in Unix/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter)
- [Command line options style - POSIX or what?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70357/command-line-options-style-posix-or-what)
- [What is the general syntax of a Unix shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160083/what-is-the-general-syntax-of-a-unix-shell-command)

Comment: @muru Thanks for the edit, I wrote on my phone and it needed some cleanup!

Answer (score 3):

#### About arguments

Like @kos mentions, the use of either `-`, `--` or no hyphen *at all* is up to the choice of the developer of the program.

The command to run the program itself is the first argument (index `0`), the second argument (and further) is defined by the application.

An example in python:

```py
if sys.argv[1] == "peanutbutter":
    print("monkey")
```

will print "monkey" if the application is called with:

```
<application> peanutbutter
```

If the code is:

```py
if sys.argv[1] == "--peanutbutter":
    print("monkey")
```

The same will happen when the application is run with:

```
<application> --peanutbutter
```

As simple as that. Often, either the use of `-` or `--` is *conventional*.

Comment: It's all up to the developer but the developer should know the convention before deciding to violate it.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Obviously, there are various opinions on "THE" convention, since all variants exist. It is a matter of style, the same as conventions on using capitals in classes and functions in coding. There is no law on this, so please don't suggest there is one size for all her.

Comment: I did `not` suggest one size fits all here.

Comment: @H2ONaCl the explanation is simple, you are looking for something there isn't.

Comment: I think steeldriver's link to GNU documentation satisfies the description "general rules" so I think I found it.

Comment: @H2ONaCl then I suggest you re- read the section on "how to answer a question". And next time, please don't change the question after answers have been posted.

Comment: I did not change it. I was asked to edit in response to a dupe suggestion. The edit is marked `edit`. If there are more edits I am not responsible.

Answer (score 2):

`-` is usually only followed by a single character. This is a heritage from Unix. `--` is usually followed by multiple characters (generally words or sentences), this comes from the GNU project. Usually commands (mainly GNU utilities) come with two parameter types, `-` and `--`. For example, in the `ls` command, the `-a` and the `--all` parameters do the exact same thing, but one is an entire word and another is a single letter.

Having an entire word as a parameter may be helpful for scripts, for example, because developers can read them and interpret the commands' parameters more easily.

In the other hand, having a single letter parameter may become handy when you are in a terminal and want to run commands faster.

If you're in doubt about the parameters a command can take, you can try a few commands like:

```
command --help
command -?
man command
```

The `man` command will give a more detailed explanation, but some commands do not have man (manual) pages.

Comment: After reading steeldriver's link it seems that  `ls -lat` is three options so it is equivalent to `ls -l -a -t` but `ls --lat` would be a single option, probably undefined as of today.

Comment: Hey, -lat and --lat are not the same. You can only pass ONE argument at a time using --. It is usually an entire word. The equivalent to -lat in the long form would be '-l --all -t'. There are no long versions for '-l' and '-t' in ls.

Comment: Yes, I know, they're not the same. `ls --lat` is undefined (today) and when it becomes defined it will not be the same as `ls -lat` (probably) .

Answer (score 2):

Generally a command line has three parts:

```
command -option argument
```

So, `-` this one is known as option and `--` this one is called long option.
It basically almost do the same jobs, but you have to defy your options clearly with the later one.

Here are some example of `-` and `--` you can use with the command `ls`

[image]